# Problem with deleting record from linear list (C)

Tags: c, function, linked-list, structure, record

At first, I would say sorry for my English, but i hope you will understand me and I need realy fast answer...

I am coding my project in C to school, and I have some trouble with deleting a record from my linear list.
I am reading the records from the text file, and I write it to a linear linked list. I will not post here the whole program, just function "vstup_z".

These records are something like a database of houses and flats (their price, city, expanse etc). And this function is scanning the string, and it should delete the whole particular record, when the scanned string is a substring of the item presenting the name of city. For example when I have in my records some flat from London and I will call this function in the program (for example "z Lon"), this function will delete this record.

Here is some code of my function:

```
void vstup_z(REALITY **p_first)
{
    REALITY *p_act = NULL, *p_help = NULL;
    char s[51] = "", arr_city[51] = "", city[51] = "";
    int counter = 0, i = 0;

    getchar();
    gets(arr_city);

// this function is working even with upper or lower case, it doesnt matter
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(arr_city); i++)  
    {
        arr_city[i] = tolower(arr_city[i]);
    }

    p_act = *p_first;
    while (p_act != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(city, p_act->miesto_ponuky); //miesto_ponuky is item in my record in slovak language
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(city); i++)
        {
            city[i] = tolower(city[i]);
        }

        if ((strstr(city, arr_city)) != NULL)
        {
            if (p_act != *p_first)
            {
                p_help->p_next = p_act->p_next; //one of the items in my record (structure) is pointer on next record
                free(p_act);
                p_act = p_help;
            }
            else
            {
                *p_first = p_act->p_next;
                free(p_act);
                p_act = *p_first; 
            }

            counter++; // how many records did i deleted
        }   

        p_help = p_act;
        if (p_act != NULL)
        {
            p_act = p_act->p_next;  
        }

    }   
    printf("Vymazalo sa %d zaznamov\n", counter); // just some text in slovak language how many records i deleted... 
}
```

In my next function (which is working 100% right) i am writing this linked list on the display...

What's my problem ?

General info about my issue:

1. I can't delete all records.
2. When i have for example 1 record in list I can delete it - it works.
3. When I have 5 records in list, I can delete 4 of them, but never all of them, and it is a problem...
4. When I have 5 records, and 3 of them have an item with name of the city, for example London, and the next two have an item with the name of city Washington, and I call this function in program like "z o" - it should delete every record whose item presenting the name of city contains character "o"; it means it should delete all of them. But it will always save the last one (but when my list consists of just one record, it will delete it right).

Sorry for my bad English. I hope you understand; if not, never mind...

Any solutions ?

Comment: Please read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). StackOverflow is not a "do my homework" forum, and your interest is to learn how to do your homework by yourself. Debugging skills are essential to every software developer. See also http://norvig.com/21-days.html

Comment: regarding: `gets(arr_city);`  The function: `gets()` has been depreciated for some years and completely removed from the latest version of the C language standard.  Strongly suggest using `fgets()`  (which has a different parameter list, read the MAN page for details)

Comment: Regarding C programming, read also [some C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and perhaps glance into [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). Avoid [undefined behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) and obsolete functions like `gets`. Consider using instead [fgets](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm), [readline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline), [getline](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)

Comment: Regarding linked lists, read the [wikipage on linked lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list). You might want to use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to debug dynamic memory issues

Comment: regarding: `(for example "z Lon"),`  This seems to indicate that the selected city to delete is from a command line parameter, but the actual code is expecting the user to type in the city.   Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
 while (p_act != NULL)
 ...
 p_help = p_act;

 if (p_act != NULL)
 {
     p_act = p_act->p_next;  
 }
```

the statement: `p_act = p_act->p_next;` causes `p_act` to point to NULL, however, there is still an entry in the list (pointed to by `p_help`) to be checked (and possibly deleted)